r3f / threejs - shoot raycast on Splat objects
we wish to place annotations on splat surfaces and we are struggling with shooting the raycast to splat objects. Here is what we tried to do:
const { camera, gl, scene } = useThree();
  <Canvas>
  <Splat
    src={URL}
    onClick={(e) => {
      console.log(
        "clicking here",
        e,
        e.point
      );
      const newMesh = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.05),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
          color: new THREE.Color("red"),
        })
      );
      newMesh.position.set(
        e.point.x,
        e.point.y,
        e.point.z
      );
      scene.add(newMesh);
    }}
  />
  </Canvas>

Indeed the raycast intersect with some elements floating in the air since the Splat appears to function as a pointcloud and some particles are found in the air. Furthermore, the onClick handler never gets triggered when we shoot the raycaster from certain camera orientations.
Do you have anything in mind to get intersections in the splat surfaces work?
Examples of intersection not being stuck in the splat surfaces but floating in the air instead



Could you resolve it already?
I'm working on the same topic. My workaround is to  place an invisible  around the object to get a raycaster:
<Splat renderOrder={renderOrder} src={'./path/to/my.splat'} />
<RigidBody type="fixed">
  <mesh
    renderOrder={renderOrder+1}
    ref={meshRef}
    onClick={onMachineClick}
    onPointerOver={handlePointerOver}
    onPointerOut={handlePointerOut}
    name="my_splat"
    position={[0, 0, 0]}
    material={transparentMaterial}>
    <boxGeometry args={[3, 2, 1.5]} />
  </mesh>
  {hovered && (
    <Html
      position={[0.5, 0.5, 0]}
      center
      distanceFactor={8}
      style={{ pointerEvents: 'none' }}>
      <Label title={'Lasercutter'} content={'Click me!'} />
    </Html>
  )}
</RigidBody>


